# How to get the filename of dropped file in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, swiftui

I have been trying to find out how to get the filename of an image dropped into a SwiftUI View.

The code fragment is as follows:

```
struct MainView: View, DropDelegate {

  @ObservedObject var userState : UserState

  var body : some View {
    Group {
      if (self.userState.editing) {
        BlackoutView()
      } else {
        DropView()
      }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 320, idealWidth: 640, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 240, idealHeight: 480, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    .onDrop(of: [(kUTTypeImage as String), "public.pdf"], delegate: self)
  }

  func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
    let proposal = DropProposal.init(operation: .copy)
    return proposal
  }

  func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    print("perform drop")
    userState.editing = true
    return true
  }

}
```

When I drop an image onto the app, it runs `performDrop`. How can one obtain the filename of the image dropped onto the app?

It runs on macOS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Having spent more than an hour struggling with the apis (the documentation is almost nonexistent), here is what worked for me:

```
// The onDrop registration
.onDrop(of: [(kUTTypeFileURL as String)], delegate: self)
```

...

```
func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {

    guard let itemProvider = info.itemProviders(for: [(kUTTypeFileURL as String)]).first else { return false }

    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: (kUTTypeFileURL as String), options: nil) {item, error in
        guard let data = item as? Data, let url = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil) else { return }
        // Do something with the file url
        // remember to dispatch on main in case of a @State change
    }

    return true
}
```

Please note that I have omitted any validation, so this code grabs the first url from any dropped files