# SwiftUI onDrop not working for audio files

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'd like to be able to drag and drop audio files into a SwiftUI view. I've implemented [`onDrop`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondrop(of:istargeted:perform:)-982eu) like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Drop some audio file here")
            .onDrop(of: [.audio], isTargeted: nil, perform: { file in
                print("Dropped audio \(file)")
                return true
            })
    }
}
```

But nothing happens if I drag and drop audio files into the resulting app's text label on macOS.

Comment: Are you trying to get the file's URL, or to use the file's content? Your question is not clear. Parts are missing in your code. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/58580471/2227743

Comment: I just want the file's URL.